# Image Rotation Performance AS3

Tags: image, performance, actionscript-3, vector, rotation

I have a vector image which I am using to highlight a segment of a circle, and I am rotating this around its central point. I am finding this is causing a fairly high amount of CPU to be used and I was wondering if anyone knows of anything I could use to improve this?

I know that I cannot use the cacheAsBitmap property when I am rotating a DisplayObject. I have tried creating my own Bitmap instead of a vector image but I didn't notice any improvement in performance.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Starling will allow you to achieve desired framerate, but rotating the image won't be so easy... I have the same problem and I must experiment with MatrixTransformations :/

Comment: hmm okay... Would using the transformation matrix help me with this problem then do you think?